# Pygame not showing anything in the window

Tags: python, pygame

Just started programming in python and pygames.
Whenever I try running a py file with pygames, the pygames window will appear, but there will be absolutely nothing in it. No errors in the log, but nothing shows, it's just a gray screen.
I tried running it on IDLE, and through the command line (I'm on a mac so I use the terminal)

And it's not just my programs that aren't showing anything, I've tried to run one of pygames examples, and it will still not display anything. For example, if I run the pygames alien example, the window will appear with a blank gray background. I'll hear the audio for the program, but no display.

Anything would help, I'm at a loss especially since no errors are showing in the log.

EDIT1:
I'm using Python 3 (and I really need to keep using Python 3)

EDIT2:
I'm using python 3.7. pygames version 1.9.4. The examples are with the pygames, they were downloaded together, so I assume it's for that version.

EDIT3:
ok, my OS is Mojave 10.14. I've tried starting the application by: opening the file, running it on IDLE, and running it through the command line, none have worked. python2 is installed, but when I run the pygame it's a python3 file

Comment: What version of python are you running, and what do the examples expect?

Comment: Python 3 has many versions. What version is your Python3, and what version are the examples written for?

Comment: Please add a lot more details-- your OS, how you're starting the app, whether or not python2 is installed, anything else you think might help.

Comment: I've added more info to the question body

Comment: On work PC so I can't check from here, but are you calling the app through Idle3/python3? And if you have multiple versions of Py3 installed, are you sure you're opening it through py3.7? (Or, from another point, have you tried calling it with other versions of Py3?)

Answer (score 2):

Known issue with Mojave - see their issue tracking: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555

Comment: any fix to this?

Comment: Sadly, I never found a solution to this. :(

Comment: I had the same problem on Catalina. The issue link above has a solution that worked for me: "sudo pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6"

Answer (score 2):

You can also install new pygame using `pip install pygame=2.0.0.dev6`. This
worked in my case.

Comment: yeah, use the latest version also works in my computer, can try this one.

Comment: Yes, this command worked in my case. Just that I had to change `pip install pygame=2.0.0.dev6` to `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`.